# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-9: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, beautifulsoup, nltk

I've been working on a program to go through various links that I already have saved in a text file, which are mostly summer opportunities/camps/etc. and scrape through them to see if key words like "scholarship" or "financial aid" pop up. However, when I run through it, it gives me the error that's in the title above.

This question has been asked a few times, but it appears to be for different reasons for different people. Therefore, I get that there's probably an error involving Unicode, but I have no idea where or why that would be.

This is the code:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import nltk

file_from = open("links.txt", "r")
list_of_urls = file_from.read().splitlines()

aid_words = ["financial", "aid", "merit", "scholarship"]

count = 0

fin_aid = []

while count <= 10:
    for url in list_of_urls:
        clean = 1
        result = "nothing found"
        source = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        print (str(url).upper())
        for links in soup.findAll('p', text = True):
            tokenized_text = nltk.word_tokenize(links)
            for word in tokenized_text:
                if word not in aid_words:
                    print ("not it " + str(clean))
                    clean += 1
                    pass
                else:
                    result = str(word)
                    print (result)
                    fin_aid.append(url)
                    break
    count += 1
    the_golden_book = {"link: ": str(url), "word found: ": str(result)}
    fin_aid.append(the_golden_book)

file_to = open("links_with_aid.txt", "w")
file_to.write(str(fin_aid))
file_to.close()

print ("scrape finished")
print (str(fin_aid))
```

Basically, I wanted to take all the links from links.txt, visit the first ten (as a test), search for the four words in the list "aid_words", and return results in the form of "not it" and the number of words searched so far, if none of the words have been found yet, or the word that was detected if one is found (so that I can visit the link later and search for it, to see if it's a false alarm or not).

When I run this through the Command Prompt, this is the stuff it shows me right before the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finaid.py", line 20, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(plain_text.encode("utf-8"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1522, in __init__
    BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1147, in __init__
    self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1189, in _feed
    SGMLParser.feed(self, markup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sgmllib.py", line 104, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sgmllib.py", line 143, in goahead
    k = self.parse_endtag(i)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sgmllib.py", line 320, in parse_endtag
    self.finish_endtag(tag)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sgmllib.py", line 358, in finish_endtag
    method = getattr(self, 'end_' + tag)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-9: ordin
al not in range(128)
```

I'm running this on Python 2.7.10, and I'm on Windows 8.1. Thanks for any help you can provide! As far as I can tell, it shouldn't be anything in "link.txt", which is literally just links that a colleague crawled and saved earlier.

Comment: 1. the code and the traceback do *not* match. Show the traceback that corresponds to the actual code. 2. Don't dump all the code, create a [minimal (but complete) code example instead](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 3. Unrelated: avoid `str()` in this case -- your usage is either an error or there are better alternatives.

Comment: Short answer: Use `python3`, Long answer: 5 years on working with text I still get the problem in `python2.x`, user `python3`

Comment: When I run this on Python 3 (with all the necessary adjustments), it gives "expected string or buffer", which I find even more confusing. It gives the error for the line where I use 'word_tokenize'. I'm more familiar with BeautifulSoup and nltk than other things--is there any way to fix this error without NOT using those two?

Comment: @alvas: Python 3 makes it easy to detect some Unicode issues but it is not a pixie dust. Unless OP will learn how to work with Unicode (first step: remove dubious `str()` usage); the issues won't fly away to the Neverland.

Answer (score 1):

I do quite a bit of website scraping and I can tell you this: please try to write your scraper code using Python 3. As soon as I updated my scrapers to use Python 3 a lot of my encoding issues went away. Be sure on your file write to use 'a' instead of 'w' if you do go to Python 3 and you want to keep the contents of that file intact.

Let me know if you have specific questions about making that transition.

On the "expected string or buffer," that usually shows up for me when I pass in an object instead of a string. To check that is happening, use a print statement to check, like so:

```
for links in soup.findAll('p', text = True):
    print(links)
    tokenized_text = nltk.word_tokenize(links)
```

If it doesn't print text to your terminal (or wherever you are running the script from) then you are passing in an object when it is expecting to receive a string.

Pseudo-code to fix it might look like:

```
for links in soup.findAll('p', text = True):
    links = links.text()
    tokenized_text = nltk.word_tokenize(links)
```

Comment: I actually have 3.4 on my computer. I tried out 2.7 because several other laptops we have run Ubuntu with only 2.7, and one of my colleagues has a Mac with 2.7 by default.

I originally wrote in 3.4, but it gives a different error: "Expected string or buffer". I've looked that up, too, but I can't find out how that applies to my post either.

Comment: I might be going at this wrong, but couldn't you do something like this and bypass using nltk alltogether? I haven't used that module, so I'll admit I'm not as familiar with it..    http://pastebin.com/cvHKfer0  (I can't figure out how to post code in a comment to an answer :(